# Out of memory - Android

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I'm using ffmpeg in my Android application and sometimes I'm getting out of memory error, I'm calling the ffmpeg inside a HandlerThread, is it ok to catch out of memory error and exit the thread while the main thread keeps on running?

I read a lot of this being not a good practice, the thing is that I really need that because I have to edit the DB when there is any kind of error

```
    fc = new FfmpegController(context, fileTmp);
    try {

        fc.processVideo(clip_in, clip_out, false,
                new ShellUtils.ShellCallback() {

                    @Override
                    public void shellOut(String shellLine) {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                         //Update the DB  
                    }
                });
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        //update the DB 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No something is going wrong if you are getting OutOfMemory errors. I would look into buffering your audio, as likely you are running the whole clip through ffmpeg at once, which is going to use up alot of memory.

Also, keep in mind that lots of us doing Audio in Android end up using the NDK primarily because of issues like you are experiencing. Audio has to be really high performance, and using the NDK allows you to write more low level memory efficient audio handling.

Android's AudioTrack has a write method that allows you to push an Audio buffer to it. A warning that this is not entry level and requires some knowledge of AudioBuffer's as well as requires you to read buffers in, send them to ffmpeg and then pass to AudioTrack. Not easy to do, and unfortunately more advanced audio on Android is not easy.

Comment: How can I buffer the audio?

Comment: @AdroidFreak edited to update my answer. It requires using AudioTrack. There are some guides online, but a warning that it nor is Audio in general easy on Android.